# style applied to table but td:hover is ignored

Tags: html, css

Been digging around and to the best of my understanding, I've applied the solutions I found when similar questions were asked but hover is being ignored. What am I missing?

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .testTable td {
            color: white;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: #44749D;
            padding: 4px;
            text-align: center;            
        }
       .testTable td:hover {
            color: 44749D !important;
            background-color: C6D4E1 !important;
        }            
    </style>

<head>
    <title>Table Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="testTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Tried with and without "!important" and with and without using a class name. IE, td {...} vs .testTable td{...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This CSS. Your Are Missing (#) at the begining of Color ( HEX Color Value )

```
 <style type="text/css">
        .testTable td {
            color: white;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: #44749D;
            padding: 4px;
            text-align: center;            
        }
       .testTable td:hover {
            color: #44749D !important;
            background-color: #C6D4E1 !important;
        }            
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

missing **#** before color. like background-color: #44749D;

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .testTable td {
            color: white;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: #44749D;
            padding: 4px;
            text-align: center;            
        }
       .testTable td:hover {
            color: #44749D !important;
            background-color: #C6D4E1 !important;
        }            
    </style>

<head>
    <title>Table Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="testTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot # in color &  background-color;

```
            .testTable td:hover {
                color: #44749D !important;
                background-color: #C6D4E1 !important;
            }
```

You can even remove !important now as it doesn't make much sense now.

```
             .testTable td:hover {
                    color: #44749D;
                    background-color: #C6D4E1;
                }
```

replace the code and bingo it will work :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll go back to my corner now . . .

Comment: You are welcome :) If it has solved your issue please mark it as answer